# State management in Istio - Kafka or not?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, istio

How do you manage state in a service mesh in Istio?

I can see that Kafka streams is one option.

How do you manage state in Istio/Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my presumption state is a temporary result of doing some process and therefore process has a record of previous interactions and can respond, based on it and keep tracking on the results. Generally, Kubernetes stores all key values of objects and interactions in [ETCD](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/) storage, therefore it's a critical function to keep `etcd` storage running to provide a wide cluster components stability. Recently I've found [ReShifter](https://github.com/mhausenblas/reshifter) very useful tool for Kubernetes cluster state management tasks as it natively uses `etcd` API queries for retrieving some specific information.

[Istio](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/) service mesh is a network management ad-don for Kubernetes with a wide range of network traffic control, load balancing, security authentication and authorization features, etc. Istio deploys its own components by injecting a  sidecar in the particular Kubernetes Pod, therefore it uses native Kubernetes state and event storage warehouse `etcd`.

Depending on the purpose of using stateful application it can be feasible to manipulate with some messaging queue systems like [Kafka](https://imti.co/kafka-kubernetes/), [RabbitMQ](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/clustered-rabbitmq-kubernetes/) in order to manage pipelines and application streams with a lot of customization opportunities. Kafka also consists of [Zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/) the key component for maintaining of the configuration information and centralizing group of services.